# Redis mass insertion ghost entries?

Tags: redis

This is the hexdump of the file I pipe into redis via a nodejs converter:

```
me@myself ~/scripts $ cat example.txt | node redisProtocol.js | hexdump -C

00000000  2a 39 0d 0a 24 34 0d 0a  53 41 44 44 0d 0a 24 37  |*9..$4..SADD..$7|
00000010  0d 0a 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e  73 0d 0a 24 31 34 0d 0a  |..domains..$14..|
00000020  77 77 77 2e 72 65 64 64  69 74 2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a  |www.reddit.com..|
00000030  24 34 0d 0a 53 41 44 44  0d 0a 24 37 0d 0a 64 6f  |$4..SADD..$7..do|
00000040  6d 61 69 6e 73 0d 0a 24  31 33 0d 0a 77 77 77 2e  |mains..$13..www.|
00000050  34 63 68 61 6e 2e 6f 72  67 0d 0a 24 34 0d 0a 53  |4chan.org..$4..S|
00000060  41 44 44 0d 0a 24 37 0d  0a 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 73  |ADD..$7..domains|
00000070  0d 0a 24 31 36 0d 0a 77  77 77 2e 66 61 63 65 62  |..$16..www.faceb|
00000080  6f 6f 6b 2e 63 6f 6d 0d  0a                       |ook.com..|
00000089
```

when piping to `redis-cli --pipe` I get:

```
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 1
```

Which is good.
Now looking into the redis DB executing `smembers domains` I get:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> smembers domains
1) "domains"
2) "SADD"
3) "www.reddit.com"
4) "www.4chan.org"
5) "www.facebook.com"
```

Where do the additional entries "domains" and "SADD" come from? The hexdump looks good, doesn't it?

Using redis version `redis-cli 2.6.7`. Thanks a lot for any help provided.
Best,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not look good. I suppose you expect the hexdump to represent:

```
SADD domains www.reddit.com
SADD domains www.4chan.org
SADD domains www.facebook.com
```

However, it starts by '*9' which means Redis expects a command with nine parameters. So Redis processes:

```
SADD domains www.reddit.com SADD domains www.4chan.org SADD domains www.facebook.com
```

which gives the result you had.

You need either to execute 3 commands in your stream, each of them starting with *3, or just one command containing:

```
SADD domains www.reddit.com www.4chan.org www.facebook.com
```

starting with *5